# JAXB unmarshalling object in object

Tags: jaxb, annotations, unmarshalling

I cant unmarshall xml because don't understand how to annotate object class in the another object. Please help.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ODZ xmlns="http://www.company.com/1.0" >
    <Data DataID="ZZZ">
        <UserData UserKey="user_001">
                 <UserEvent>...</UserEvent>
            </UserData> 
     </Data>
</ODZ>
```

Container classes:
I. First level with link to the second (**ODZ -> Data**).

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name = "ODZ", namespace = "http://www.company.com/1.0")
public class ODZContainer {

    private ImportContainer importContainer;

    @XmlElement (name = "Data", type=ImportContainer.class)
    public ImportContainer getImportContainer() {
        return importContainer;
    }
}
```

II. Second level with link to the third level(**Data -> UserData**).

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Data")
public class ImportContainer {

    private String DataID;
    private ArrayList<UserDataBean> userDataBean;

    @XmlElement (name = "UserData", type=UserDataBean.class)
    public ArrayList<UserDataBean> getUserDataBean() {
        return userDataBean;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name = "DataID")
    public String getDataID() {
        return DataID;
    }
}
```

III. Third level with link to the fourth level(**UserData-> UserEvent**).

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
    @XmlRootElement(name = "UserData")
    public class UserDataBean {
        private ArrayList<UserEventBean> userEventData;
        private String userEventID;

        @XmlAttribute(name = "UserKey")
        public String getUserEventID() {
            return userEventID;
        }

        @XmlElement (name = "UserEvent", type=UserEventBean.class)
        public ArrayList<UserEventBean> getUserEventBean() {
            return userEventData;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace qualification in your JAXB metadata does not match your XML.  You can use the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation to specify the namespace qualification for your model.

```java
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://www.company.com/1.0",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

**For More Information on JAXB and Namespaces**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

---

**Notes About Your Metadata**

Since the type of the `ArrayList` is already specified, you don't need to specify it via the `@XmlElement` annotation.  It doesn't hurt, but its not necessary.

```
@XmlElement (name = "UserData", type=UserDataBean.class)
public ArrayList<UserDataBean> getUserDataBean() {
    return userDataBean;
}
```

`@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` means that nothing is mapped unless it is explicitly annotated.  This may or not be what you want.  You may find the following article useful:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Please answer for one question. Is that corrent using: `@XmlElement (name = "Data", type=ImportContainer.class)` in the parent class and `@XmlRootElement(name = "Data") public class ImportContainer {`.. in the child?